# octave opengl_renderer: Error 1286 occurred in init_gl_context

Tags: gnuplot, octave

When I use function plot or imagesc to draw a figure I'm getting these errors.
Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The typically important informations are all missing: Which GNU Octave version, which OS, OpenGL driver and GPU. Perhaps a old mesa driver...

Comment: Octave’s version is 4.2.0
my operation sysetem is mac os sierra
cpu   core i5 4258u
OpenGL version 4.1 APPLE-12.4.2                                                                   thx!

Comment: 1286 is "GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION 0x0506" If I google for Mac OS and this error I get many hits and I doubt this is a GNU Octave problem.

Comment: I solved this problem by executing "graphics_toolkit('gnuplot')".

Answer (score 16):

By default, homebrew installed my Octave with "qt" as the default for graphics. You can make Octave startup by using "gnuplot" instead by editing the file

> ~/.octaverc

(where ~ is your home directory) and putting the line of code:

```
  graphics_toolkit("gnuplot");
```